# Couldn't fetch mysqli...Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm totally baffled. My entire page code is below.

Originally, I had the include header.php, sidebar, topMenuBar, & mainContentShell at the top of the page, ran the first query after it, and then the second query, etc for the rest of the page. Everything worked. My first query was different though... I checked that the $_GET['stone'] number was greater than zero and less than the select max(StoneID), but I could still get errors if someone manually put in the StoneID for a stone that was deleted from inventory. I revised my $_GET validation plan, and moved it above the included files so the header() redirect would work properly. Now, my second query won't work, even though it is completely unchanged.

**Var_dump($querySN)** yields **string(53) "select StoneName from stonetypes where StoneID = '1' "** and **var_dump($resultSN)** yields **NULL**.
It states: error occurred at line 35 ---  $resultSN = $db->query($querySN);
States several times: Couldn't fetch mysqli
States a number of times: Property access is not allowed yet
And states in conclusion: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object on line 36---$rowSN = $resultSN->fetch_assoc();

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can fix it? Page code follows. Thanks!!!

```
<?php 
require('./inc/config.inc.php');

$stone = (INT)$_GET['stone'];   

require(MYSQL1);

$queryCk = "select StoneID from stonetypes";
$resultCk = $db->query($queryCk);
$var = array();
while ($rowCk = $resultCk->fetch_assoc()){
     $var[] = $rowCk['StoneID'];
}

if(!in_array($stone, $var)) {
     header('Location: beadgallery.php?type=stones');
     exit;
} else {


include('inc/header.inc.php');
include('inc/sidebar.inc.php');
include('inc/topMenuBar.inc.php');
include('inc/mainContentShell.inc.php');
?>

<div id="mainContent">
<div class="center">

<?php


             $querySN = "select StoneName from stonetypes where StoneID = '$stone' ";
             $resultSN = $db->query($querySN);
             $rowSN = $resultSN->fetch_assoc();

                echo '<table id="cartDisplayTable">';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td colspan="2">';
                        echo '<table id="titleTable">';
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td id="stoneTitle">';
                            if (isset($rowSN['StoneName'])){
                            echo '<h2>'.ucwords($rowSN['StoneName']).'</h2>';}
                            echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

             $query = "select * from organized_inventory2 where StoneID = '$stone' ";
             $result = $db->query($query);

             $num_beadItems = $result->num_rows;
                $justused='abc';
                for ($i=0; $i < $num_beadItems; $i++) {
                    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

                    if (!isset($row['itmphoto'])) {
                                    echo '</table>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                        echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr id="cartDivider"></td></tr>';

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td id="cartImgCell">';
                        echo '<img src="img/nophoto.gif">';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td id="cartInfoCell">';
                            echo '<table id="innerTable">';
                                    include ('inc/stoneCartInfo.inc.php');

                    } elseif ($row['itmphoto'] == $justused) {
                                echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr id="itemDivider"></td></tr>';
                                    include ('inc/stoneCartInfo.inc.php');

                    } else {

                                    echo '</table>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>'
                        ;

                    echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr id="cartDivider"></td></tr>'
                    ;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td id="cartImgCell">';

                        echo '<img src="img/invent/'.$row['itmphoto'].'">';
                        $justused = $row['itmphoto'];

                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td id="cartInfoCell">';
                            echo '<table id="innerTable">';
                                    include ('inc/stoneCartInfo.inc.php');                  }
                    }

                                    echo '</table>'
                                    ;
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>'
                        ;

                echo '</table>'
                ;
            } 
                 $result->free();
                 unset($result);
             $db->close();


        ?>

    </div> <!-- div class="center" -->

</div> <!-- div id="mainContent" -->
```

Comment: Have you checked that else condition closing brace is not there or you have not mentioned here?

Answer (score 1):

Integers don't nee quotes around the value as in **StoneID = '1'**, this shouldn't be a problem  because MySQL should typecast.

You have not checked what "$result" contains, if it's boolean then the query failed and you need to see the output of [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).